# How can I save multiple radio button options as a variable using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a list of options for pizza toppings, and want to save the user's input as variable. Since typically most people will choose more than one topping, how can I capture that input as a single variable?

```
            <p class="selectors">Toppings:</p>
            <input type="radio" name="cheese" value="cheese">Cheese<br>
            <input type="radio" name="pepperoni" 
             value="pepperoni">Pepperoni<br>
            <input type="radio" name="sausage" 
             value="sausage">Sausage<br>
            <input type="radio" name="onions" value="onions">Onions<br>
            <input type="radio" name="greenPeppers" 
             value="greenPeppers">Green Peppers<br>


$(document).ready(function(event){
  $("#mainForm").submit(function(event){
    var toppings = $('????').val();
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first. The way you are selecting the radio buttons are wrong. It's like checkboxes. You should have only one name for all the radio buttons.

And secondly, use a class or name selector this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(event) {
  $("#mainForm").submit(function(event) {
    var toppings = "Nothing selected!";
    if ($(".flavour:checked").length > 0)
      toppings = $(".flavour:checked").val();
    console.log(toppings);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="mainForm">
  <p class="selectors">Toppings:</p>
  <input type="radio" name="flavour" class="flavour" value="cheese">Cheese<br />
  <input type="radio" name="flavour" class="flavour" value="pepperoni">Pepperoni<br />
  <input type="radio" name="flavour" class="flavour" value="sausage">Sausage<br />
  <input type="radio" name="flavour" class="flavour" value="onions">Onions<br />
  <input type="radio" name="flavour" class="flavour" value="greenPeppers">Green Peppers<br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Else, if you need multiple choices, use a [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```js
$(document).ready(function(event) {
  $("#mainForm").submit(function(event) {
    var toppings = "Nothing selected!";
    if ($(".flavour:checked").length > 0)
      toppings = $(".flavour:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
      }).get().join();
    console.log(toppings);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="mainForm">
  <p class="selectors">Toppings:</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cheese" class="flavour" value="cheese">Cheese<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="pepperoni" class="flavour" value="pepperoni">Pepperoni<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="sausage" class="flavour" value="sausage">Sausage<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="onions" class="flavour" value="onions">Onions<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="greenPeppers" class="flavour" value="greenPeppers">Green Peppers<br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```